# Rust closure as a method of struct

Tags: rust, closures

how can I call a closure receiving my struct as parameter and holding that closure as member?

```rust
type Thunk = Box<dyn FnMut(&mut Config) + Send + 'static>;

struct Config {
    s: String,
    f: Thunk,
}

impl Config {
    fn run(&mut self) {
        // the problem is here
        (self.f)(self);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let cfg = Config {s: String::from("hello"), f: Box::new( |c| {
        println!("{}", c.s);
    }) };
}
```

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:11:18
   |
11 |         (self.f)(self);
   |         -------- ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
   |         |
   |         first mutable borrow occurs here
   |         first borrow later used by call
```

Comment: You can use a [cyclical RC](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.new_cyclic) but that might muddy up the types a bit

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible in general, due to Rust safety rules - callback borrows itself exclusively for the duration of the call, so you can't simultaneously borrow the whole struct again.

To see why this is not only a theoretical problem, consider this:

```
type Thunk = Box<dyn FnMut(&mut Config) + Send + 'static>;

struct Config {
    s: String,
    f: Thunk,
}

impl Config {
    fn run(&mut self) {
        // the problem is here
        (self.f)(self);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = String::from("temporary");
    let cfg = Config {s: String::from("hello"), f: Box::new(move |c| {
        c.f = Box::new(|_| {});
        println!("{}", s);
    }) };
}
```

In this code, we have the callback which essentially drops itself while it is running. Since it captures `s` by-move, `s` is dropped along with callback. Then the callback tries to print `s` - and if that was allowed, we've had a use-after-free.

---

The solution will depend on the real requirements. The easiest way to go is to separate the configuration, passing to the `Thunk` only the part which doesn't contain the `Thunk` itself.

Comment: Hm, have never thought about it in that way. Thank you!